# How to convert epoch time to time_point

Tags: c++, c++11

In some place I already get the epoch time value like this:

```
int64_t timeSeconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(m_startTime.time_since_epoch()).count()
```

But how to convert this back to "std::chrono::system_clock::time_point"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp{std::chrono::seconds{timeSeconds}};
```

- Turn the integral type into `seconds` and then turn this `duration` into a `time_point`.