# How to convert epoch count in milliseconds to chrono time_point

Tags: c++, date, datetime, c++-chrono

I am trying to convert epoch count in milliseconds (e.g., `1699491717000`) to a C++ `chrono` `time_point`. I have tried the following commands and none of them worked for me.

1. I tried Howard Hinnant [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57944731/1227860) but the compiler did not like it

   ```
   std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp{std::chrono::milliseconds{epoch_count_ms}};
   // Compiler says
   // No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::chrono::milliseconds' (aka 'duration<long, ratio<1, 1000>>')
   ```
2. ```
    std::chrono::milliseconds epoch_duration(epoch_count_ms);
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp(epoch_duration);
    // Compiler says:
    // No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::chrono::milliseconds' (aka 'duration<long, ratio<1, 1000>>')
   ```

Could someone kindly help me out?

Comment: What type is `epoch_count_ms`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`epoch_count_ms` must be an integral type.  If it is a `double` or a `string`, it will result in the error message you are seeing.

The second informational error message after the one you posted should contain this information, e.g.:

```
note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable:
no known conversion from 'double' to 'const std::chrono::duration<long long, std::ratio<1, 1000>>' for 1st argument class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS duration
                          ^^^^^^
```

This works:

```
long long epoch_count_ms = 1699491717000;
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp{std::chrono::milliseconds{epoch_count_ms}};
```